# Identifying if a sentence is positive or negative regarding a subject

Tags: python, nlp

I am new to NLP and have a question.

Given a set of sentences about waiting time at a hospital, for each sentences, I want to identify if it says the waiting time is long or short. Some examples are:

- "The waiting time is very long" -> Long
- "I waited for just a short period of time" -> Short
- "They didn't make me wait for long" -> Short
- "I wouldn't say the waiting time is long" -> Short
- ...

What would be a good way to approach this problem?
Thank you very much!

Comment: This is a problem of text classification; you can use one of the many approaches there is in the literature

Comment: @Cristofor Thank you very much. Could you give some references on "the literature"? What are those many approaches?

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-label-text-classification-with-scikit-learn-30714b7819c5

Comment: this can be a good starting point

Comment: In your case you would have only two labels